# Ошибка при попытке запроса высоты точки через API Google Elevation. unknown property lat

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-maps-api, google-maps

Пытаюсь получить высоту точки по координатам чтобы выполнить расчёты. Результат предполагается поместить в текстовое поле. До обработки ответа сервера, впрочем, дело не доходит. Ещё до отправки запроса на сервер происходит ошибка, что lat - неизвестный атрибут. На всякий: браузер - Google Chrome. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять причину.

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>some_title</title>
    </head>

        <body>
            <b>Результат</b><br>
            <textarea cols="150" rows="50" id="result" value=""></textarea>        <br>
        </body>

        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apiKey&libraries=geometry,elevation"></script>

        <script>
            var requestToServer = new XMLHttpRequest();
            requestToServer.onreadystatechange = answerReciever;

            var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
            elevator.getElevationForLocations([{lat:63.333, lng:-150.5}]);

            function answerReciever(response){
                var d = new Date();
                document.getElementById('result').value += d.toString() + '\n';
            }
        </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: Я вижу у вас как минимум две ошибки. 1 - создаете `requestToServer `, но отправку не запускаете. 2 - не правильно создаете `elevator `, не хватает скобок, должно быть так `new google.maps.ElevationService()`

Comment: 2. Если верить доке, то всё правильно; к тому же я оттуда строку и скопировал.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation?hl=ru
По ссылке см. "Примеры использования службы Elevation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Я неправильно вызывал метод getElevationForLocations.
Правильно так: getElevationForLocations({locations: arrayWithLocationObjects}, loopbackProcessingFunction).

Кроме этого, создание переменной requestToServer в коде - лишнее. Метод getElevationForLocations создаёт всё нужное сам и сам же отправляет запрос на серверы Google; нужно лишь создать функцию для обработки ответа.

Описание метода getElevationForLocations:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#ElevationService

Описание объекта LatLng: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=ru#LatLng